# "Not Contains" and "and/or" operator not properly working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

"is not in list" and "and/or" operator not working in Kotlin

Hi,

Currently I am doing a shuffle function
The app while shuffle a random number.

If the number is not yet in my list, I will add it
if already existed, continue my while loop

```
var currentItem : Int = 0
var selectionList : MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
var choiceItems : MutableList<NihongoLessonObject.LessonItems> = ArrayList()    



fun addingChoiceItems(lessonItems : NihongoLessonObject.JsonFetch) : MutableList<NihongoLessonObject.LessonItems>{
    while (choiceItems.size < 3) {
        var rnd = (0..9).random()
        if((rnd !in selectionList) and (currentItem !in selectionList)) {
            selectionList.add(rnd)
            choiceItems.add(getLessonItem(rnd, lessonItems))
        }
    }
    return choiceItems
}
```

number that is already existed in my list is still added.

sometimes I also experience forever loop if currentItem and rnd is equals.

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes I also experience forever loop if currentItem and rnd is
>   equals

They don't need to be equal to experience an infinite loop.  
When the number `0` is added to the list, then this condition

```
currentItem !in selectionList
```

is always `false` making the whole condition

```
(rnd !in selectionList) and (currentItem !in selectionList)
```

also `false`, so the loop will be executed infinitely.  
It's not clear why you need `currentItem`. 
If you need it to exclude its value from the numbers added to the list change this:

```
currentItem !in selectionList
```

to this:

```
currentItem != rnd
```

> number that is already existed in my list is still added

this is something that you have to debug and find out the case where it happens.  
With the code you provide this seems impossible. 
**Important note**: don't use the [bitwise operator `and`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/and.html) in logical expressions. 
 Use `&&` (logical `AND` operator). 
**Edit**
The title of your question contains *"and/or" ....* 
maybe you tried `or` instead of `and` in the condition? 
If you did then you could get duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your conditions, I believe the issue is with `currentItem !in selectionList`.

```
if((rnd !in selectionList) and (currentItem !in selectionList)) {
     selectionList.add(rnd)
     choiceItems.add(getLessonItem(rnd, lessonItems))
     // possibly update currentItem here.
}
```

While you're adding things to `rnd` to `selectionList`, you're not updating `currentItem`. `currentItem` is always `0`.

I would suggest adding `currentItem = rnd`, but I believe you should be able to just remove `currentItem` all together.